# Compare elements of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I want to compare 2 tuple `T1` and `T2`, which are both three-element-tuple, by firstly comparing `T[0]`, if `T1[0]==T2[0]`, then compare `T1[1]` and `T2[1]`, if `T1[1]==T2[1]` then compare `T1[2]` and `T2[2]`.

Comment: `t1 == t2` ?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to use `if-else ladder` like below

```
tup1=(1,2,3)
tup2=(1,3,4)
if(tup1[0]==tup2[0]):
    print("Elements at index 0 are same")
    if(tup1[1]==tup2[1]):
        print("Elements at index 1 are same")
        if(tup1[2]==tup2[2]):
            print("Elements at index 2 are same")
        else:
            print("Elements at index 2 are same")
    else:
        print("Elements at index 1 are not same")
else:
    print("Elements at index 0 are not same")
```

Comment: This solution has some limitations: it is restricted to tuples of length 3 and has hardcoded strings. In addition, it uses tuple indexing instead of the more Pythonic `zip`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Conditional comparison

If you wish to conditionally check whether each index of 2 tuples are equal, you can use a `for` loop and `break` when values do not match:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (1, 4, 3)

for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    if i == j:
        print(f'Index {idx} match: {i}')
    else:
        print(f'Index {idx} no match: {i} vs {j}')
        break
```

Result:

```
Index 0 match: 1
Index 1 no match: 2 vs 4
```

#### Elementwise comparison

You can use a tuple comprehension with `zip`:

```
res = tuple(i == j for i, j in zip(a, b))

# (True, False, True)
```

Alternatively, you can convert to NumPy arrays and check equality:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.array(a) == np.array(b)

# array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

#### Equality of tuples

Of course, to test whether *all* elements of 2 tuples are equal, you can simply check `a == b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping with break :

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        pass
    else:
        break
print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to control whether the next pair should be compared or not:

```
T1 = (1,2,3)
T2 = (1,4,5)

def compareTuples(T1, T2):
    index = 0
    length = len(T1)
    while index < length:
        # If they are equal, move to the next pair, else stop.
        if T1[index]==T2[index]:
            index += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Actually what is named tuple comprehension is a generator expression converted to tuple. Just for precision.